# LG 25UM65-P ultrawide with HP EliteBook 8440p no longer works in ultrawide mode

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, resolution, nvidia-graphics-card, widescreen

I have an HP EliteBook 8440p, it has the nVidia NVS3100M graphics chip in it, the rest of the machine is an i7, 8GB RAM, SSD, Win 7 Pro.

Video outs on the laptop are VGA or Display-Port.

I bought an LG ultrawide 25UM65-P screen.
It took a lot of messing but somehow managed to get it to work in full width. Not sure how otherwise I'd repeat it :P

At some point about a month ago, the nVidia drivers updated.

I lost the full-width mode.
Can't get it back.
Tried to rollback to the old driver versions, that didn't work.
Tried a Windows System Restore which failed.

Am now stuck with full HD with massive black spaces on either side of the screen.

Any pointers gratefully received.

When I originally set it up I started off using a VGA cable which would work to full resolution but looked awful.
I switched to a Display Port cable which would only work up to 1440 x 900 on a narrow screen.
I then got a Display Port - HDMI adapter and used an HDMI cable and somehow managed to get a digital signal working at 2560 x 1080. Which is lovely.

Now I'm back to 1920 x 1080, narrow screen, after the driver update and I can't get it to full width.

Answer (score 0):

An answer of sorts. It's fixed by the way.

Uninstalled every "NVidia" program.
Windows rebooted and "discovered" the new graphics card and installed its own drivers (nvidia version 3.07 rather then 3.27 which was on there before).
It came back as full HD (with the wide horizontal borders) but went in to screen resolution settings and the 2560 option was there and it's working properly.

So that's "what I did" and "what happened" but no real reason as to why:

1.) the newer drivers wouldn't work up to the full 2560 width
2.) it magically fixed itself when I went back down to an older driver

Not knocking it but would love to know reasons why, to be able to share them...